# Update to replace all fields in Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java

MongoDB has the capability to update a document by [replacing all of the fields](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#example-update-replace-fields). This is done by not passing any modifier operators.

I would like to do the same operation in Spring Data MongoOperations update* methods. In the [JavaDoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoOperations.html#upsert-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Update-java.lang.Class-), it seems that this is supported out of the box:

> update - **the update document that contains the updated object** or $ operators to manipulate the existing object

From all of the examples I found, the update parameter is created with the $ operators.

How can I create an Update object directly from my POJO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a method `Update.fromDBObject`. I think this is what the javadoc meant.

Code example:

```
DBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject();
mongoOps.getConverter().write(object, dbObject);
Update.fromDBObject(dbObject, "_id");
```